# How to fix Problem with system.data configuration in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework

If updated my project to mysql.data 8.0.13 and MySql.Data.EntityFramework. The target Framework is .net 4.5.2 EF is on 6.2
I have now the strange behavoiur that i have to add the system.data part to my configuration

```
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory,MySql.Data" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

Then it's running on some machines. But on others you get following error. (translated to english since system is german)

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: An error occurred when creating the configuration section handler for system.data: The column 'InvariantName' has the restriction that it must be unique. The value 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' already exists.
```

So if i cut out this part of the configuration it works. But on the other machine it states.

```
System.ArgumentException: The ADO.NET provider with the invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' was either not registered on the computer or in the application configuration file, or could not be loaded.
```

Is there any solution or check possible? Because i also have the strange behaviour for different users on the same pc (rolling out with clickonce)

The configuration part of EF

```
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.EntityFramework"></provider>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

This should work on any pc. I also don't really know how to add more information because I really don't know where the problem is. Tried to fix this the whole weekend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not so sure but you can try this:

From System.data elements:

Add  this:

```
<remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
```

Looks like:

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.8.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

You can include the version or remove like yours.

But if you include the version make sure that it is the MYSQL version you are using.

Comment: Tested the remove on 4 different machine with both states. worked on all of them, many thanks!